# Use of unresolved identifier 'DynamicLinkComponents'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to set up Firebase Dynamic Links. I get the error - Use of unresolved identifier 'DynamicLinkComponents'

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using swift/ios.

```
let link = URL(string: "https://test.com/?invitedby=\(MUser.sharedInstance.getUserId())")
  let referralLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link!, domain: "test.page.link")

  referralLink.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "com.test.test")
  referralLink.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1.0.1"
  referralLink.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "test"

  referralLink.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "com.test.test")
  referralLink.androidParameters?.minimumVersion = 125

  referralLink.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
    if let error = error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return
    }
    MUser.sharedInstance.setMobileReferralId(shortURL)
    self.referralLink.text = shortURL
    self.copyToClipboard()
  }
```

Comment: Is `import Firebase` in the source? What's in the Podfile?